# the value of the associated type `item` (from trait `Draw`) must be specified

Tags: rust

```
pub trait Draw {
    type item;

    fn draw(&self);
}

pub struct Screen {
    pub comps: Vec<Box<dyn Draw>>,
}

impl Screen {
    pub fn run(&self) {
        for comp in self.comps.iter() {
            comp.draw();
        }
    }
}
```

I got this error message:

```
error[E0191]: the value of the associated type `item` (from trait `Draw`) must be specified
  --> src/main.rs:12:28
   |
6  |     type item;
   |     ---------- `item` defined here
...
12 |     pub comps: Vec<Box<dyn Draw>>,
   |                            ^^^^ help: specify the associated type: `Draw<item = Type>`
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: By specifying the type of the associated type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the item concrete type while specifying trait object vec.

i.e.

```
pub struct Screen {
    pub comps: Vec<Box<dyn Draw<item = i64>>>,
}
```